# Determine if 2 points are horizontal without trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's say that I have 2 points: (c1X, c1Y) and (c2X, c2Y).

I would like to consider these 2 points horizontal as long as their angle is below 45 degrees. I could accomplish this with trigonometry.

Is there a simpler way that avoids trigonometric functions (I am implementing a program)?

Comment: do you mean the angle enclosed by the line going through these points and the $x$ axis should be less than $45$ degrees?

Comment: yes, 45 degrees up or 45 degrees down. Let's say for simplicity that c1X < c2X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the angle is always $45$ degrees, then you have to check that:
$$
-1 < \frac{c_1Y-c_2Y}{c_1X-c_2X} < 1,
$$

and the reason is that your points are "horizontal" if and only if their vertical (y) distance is smaller than their horizontal (x) distance.

You need trigonometry only with more complicated angles.

Comment: By taking the absolute value I could just check with < 1. Also since I had the same problem with the vertical relationship, you solved both with a simple formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since we know the acceptable range of the angle between the lines, we know the acceptable range of all trigonometric functions.
$0 \leq \theta < 45^{\circ} \implies 0 \leq \tan \theta < 1$. Evaluate 
$\tan \theta $ by
$$
\tan \theta = \frac{\mathrm{opposite}}{\mathrm{adjacent}} = \left | \frac{Y_{c1} - Y_{c2}}{X_{c1} - X_{c2}} \right |.
$$
Now in your program, just check that

$$
0 \leq \ \left | \frac{Y_{c1} - Y_{c2}}{X_{c1} - X_{c2}} \right | < 1.
$$

I hope this is the type of response that you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v = (c1X - c2X, c1Y - c2Y)^T$ and $e_1 = (1,0)^T$.
Then, the angle $\alpha$ enclosed between $v$ and $e_1$ satisfies
$$  \frac{v^T e_1}{\|v\| \|e_1\|} = \cos(\alpha). $$
Notice that $\cos(\pi/4) = \frac1{\sqrt 2}$.
Thus, we have $|\alpha| \le \pi / 4$ if and only if
$$ |v_1| \le \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{ v_1^2 + v_2^2 }. $$